# Can an Apache module inject configuration in runtime?

Tags: c, apache, apache2-module

I wonder if it's possible for an Apache module to change global config structures.

What I want to achieve is injecting new vhosts without Apache restart. Of course I'm aware that the changes would fully take effect after all workers have recycled, but for me - it's still better than a restart.

I've written an Apache module before, but the configuration is an unknown land to me. While reading config.c, I noticed that a function called ap_build_config() could be helpful, but how do I call it to do what I need? Is it at all possible?

Comment: FYI: http://httpd.apache.org/lists.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mailing list guys have answered this question quite well.

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/httpd-modules-dev/201006.mbox/%3cAANLkTin0pST2aEpfhNJBXVwMG7stzi7JDPEMSLftADth@mail.gmail.com%3e